# Stretching hover background to full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to adapt a use of some jscript to make links in text change the full bleed background on a single web page, my hacked attempt is here:

http://testarama.webege.com/

My problem is with smaller screens... if you resize the window then you will notice that the hover backgrounds only fill an area the size of the initial window before scrolling down... but if you are scrolled down fully and using the bottom link then this displays the cutoff with the original background poking out (the test will explain that better than I!).

I've tried various containers and background-attach rules and can't seem to get around this... I'd really like to use this trick for a site so if anyone can shed some light on where it is going wrong that'd be great.

INDEX.HTM =

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tester</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src='leaflet.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='wax.leaf.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <link href='leaflet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('p a').each(function() {
                    var fig = $('<flashers class="'+ $(this).attr('rel') +'"></flashers>');
                    fig.appendTo('body');
                });

                $('p a').hover(
                    function() {
                        $('body').addClass('hover_on');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        $('.'+$(this).attr('rel')).addClass('on');
                    },

                    function() {
                        $('body').removeClass('hover_on');
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                        $('.'+$(this).attr('rel')).removeClass('on');
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <bound>
            <div class="main_box">
                                <p>This is a background link <a rel="green">that turns green</a>.</p>
                                <p>This is more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going.</p>
                                <p>This is more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going.</p>
                                <p>This is more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going.</p>
                                <p>This is more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going.</p>
                                <p>This is more text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so forth and so on and keep going.</p>
                                <p>This is another background link <a rel="green">that turns green</a>.</p>
                <footer />
            </div>
        </bound>
    </body>
</html>
```

STYLE.CSS:

```
/*** background tester ***/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;

    }

html, body {
    height: 100%;

    }

/* Main */

body {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia, Garamond, Baskerville, serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 30px;
    background: url('red.jpg') center center #222;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

flashers {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s opacity;
        -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
    }

::selection { background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); }

/* Backgrounds */

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    flashers.on { opacity: 1; }
    flashers.green { background-image: url('green.jpg'); }
}

/* Content etc. */

bound {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: box;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
    box-pack: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    }

/* Big displays etc. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {

    p a {
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 3px;
        line-height: 0em;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
        }
    p a:not([href]) { pointer-events: auto; }
    p a:hover { opacity: 1; }

    .hover_on p a[href] { color: transparent; }
    .hover_on p a { color: transparent; }
    .hover_on p { color: transparent; }
    .hover_on p a.active { color: #fff; }
}

/* Other Fixings (some borrowed) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), screen and (max-height: 680px) {
    body { font-size: 16pt; }
    li { line-height: 1.25em; margin-bottom: 0.6em; }
}

a {
    outline: medium none !important;
}
```

Rest is visible at link: http://testarama.webege.com/

and also in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5d2fdpq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The background is set on flashers element.

And this is descendant from body. So it is dimensioned to the full dimension of body.

But **body** height is dimensioned as 100%, so it is dimensioned according to the html dimension, that at the end is the dimension of the browser window.

But when you are scrolling, the bottom of the screen is on the **bound** element, that is sized according to its content, and that, in small browser sizes, has a height greater than body.

you could try to make **body** adapt to **bound**, but probably the best solution is to make **flashers** descendant of **bound**

Haven't succeeded fully, that's the best I have got :

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5d2fdpq/2/)

```
.main_box {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    z-index: auto;
}
.main_box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 110%;
    z-index: -9;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: green;
    background-clip: border-box;
}

.main_box.active:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.green:after {
        background-image: url('http://s8.postimg.org/xj53t3d91/green.jpg');
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a great suggestion and I see why it would work but I can't figure out how to implement it... do you mean by re-ordering the divs somehow or by changing       fig.appendTo('body'); to fig.appendTo('bound');   ... because that doesn't work :/

Comment: I just can't tell you really, it's difficult to tell on a live site. Please provide a working demo, so that we can help you better.

Comment: The code above is exactly what's on the demo link at http://testarama.webege.com ... do you have a suggestion of a service I can make a working demo with? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Still struggling with this - could you tell me what you mean by 'working demo' and I will provide one if I can?

Comment: Sorry, for my late answer!  I was suggesting you to use fiddle, codepen, or similar. You can set a demo page there, and allow others to modify it. Also, you can set there a minimal example, removing all the styles and elements that are not a part of the problem. Anyway, I have been doing several test, and I have been unable to get it working. is **background: fixed** an absolute requirement ?

Comment: I put it here - https://jsfiddle.net/the_t_test_1/q5d2fdpq/ - but I don't think I put the JS in correctly as the hover function doesn't work? As for background:fixed , there are no absolute requirements at this stage... that's just where I have gotten to :/     (edited with new fiddle link)

Comment: The problem with the fiddle was that you need to select jquery as external library. The problem is harder that I thought. I have added a fiddle with my best solution so far (changing your approach)

Comment: I definitely appreciate your efforts but it's somewhat less suitable than the original since now it just bands around the text e.g. http://fiddle.jshell.net/q5d2fdpq/2/show/